# Skipping unnecessary lines when importing a csv?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, csv, parsing

I need to import a a variety of csv's, but some of them come with a bunch of filler lines in the beginning with pieces of information I don't need.  After these lines, the table begins, and I need to import this table.  How can I ignore the filler lines when the amount and text on the filler lines is not standard between the csv files?

Comment: Depends on how your data is formatted. If your data is always going to follow a predictable pattern, you could probably use python to strip lines out of the csv until it hits the first line where at least one of the fields matches a pattern (date, quantity, plu, etc.).

Comment: Edit your question with an example of the csv file. Also, explain if the "filler lines in the beginning" are going to be constants or changes with the file. In that way you might get more help.